# JQuery image select area

Tags: jquery, crop, jcrop

I found excellent jquery imageareaselect: http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/ which is used in wordpress.

Script works excellent except one thing.

For example when you have image with dimensions 1024x768 you set **imageHeight** (300) and imageWidth (400) and that works fine but problem is that you can't set cropper to round numbers.

For example you select 600x400 and what you get in selection innput's is 599x399.

Wordpress has patch for that in image-edit.js but I can't get it out to work.

Has anybody has solved that?

Thank's

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used that plugin before, but I have used jCrop before without the issue that you describe.  http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html

Comment: sorry but you gave me broken link. :(

Comment: now link work's. I have tested taht script and what I get is 601x399, I can't get 600x400 :(